# shinyAppDir not adjusting height

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, rstudio, flexdashboard

I am using `flexdashboard` with `RMarkdown` to create an application. However the height of the application does not change accordingly or as per the specified measurements.

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard not adjusting height"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
runtime: shiny
---
    
    
```{r, height=850}
library(shiny)
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package="shiny"),
  options = list(height=850)
)
```
## Another
````

I include the height option but it loads with a scroll bar (my RStudio session is shown below) [image: Shiny app loading with a scroll bar].

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.0.2        htmltools_0.5.1.1     tools_4.0.2           flexdashboard_0.5.1.1
 [5] yaml_2.2.1            rmarkdown_2.7         knitr_1.31            jsonlite_1.7.2       
 [9] xfun_0.21             digest_0.6.27         rlang_0.4.10          evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: Have you tried opening it in the browser? Sometimes Rstudio does some funny stuff..

Comment: I have tried the browser and still the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround using `CSS3` as [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/how-to-make-a-div-100-height-of-the-browser-window) and added a `fluidRow` with the `overflow` and `100vh` style.

````
---
title: "Flexdashboard not adjusting height"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    social: menu
runtime: shiny
---

```{r , height = "100%"}
library(shiny)
fluidRow(style = " overflow: auto;  height: calc(100vh - 50px) !important;",
shinyAppDir(
  system.file("examples/06_tabsets", package="shiny"))
)
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Updating your R to the latest Version could potentially fix your issue, Your code works on my machine without your issue. Also opening a fresh new project in a new directory with create a clean environment. Is your web browser set to zoom ~150%?

[image]

Comment: I think it is an RStudio version problem. Which version of RStudio are you using? I downgraded to Version 1.1.463 from Version 1.4  the app worked well

Comment: Could this be affected by the `pandoc` version? The two have different versions, `pandoc 2.11.4` in `RStudio 1.4.*` and `pandoc 1.19.2.1` in `RStudio 1.1.463 `. I tried running the app from `R` GUI with the pandoc path set to `Sys.setenv(RSTUDIO_PANDOC="C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\pandoc")` and the difference is observed

Comment: I don’t think flexdashbaords use pandoc, pandoc is only for PDF output, this is more the rendering of Rmarkdown I think